# grid.arrange does not finish plotting big plots when followed by a menu

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeout, gridextra

I have 4 ggplot objects with quite a few elements making the individual plots taking a long time to load, but they do finish adding all elements when I load them individually.

I want all the 4 plots in the same plot, which I do using `grid.arrange`
When I run each element individually (saving the plots, then run the `grid.arrange()` line alone, the plot gets rendered as expected. However, when I run my full script with ctrl+alt+R, I only get the first plot, a bit of the second plot.

Is it possible to increase the time limit so that the script can finish making the plot?

```
data<- data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))

plot1 <- plot2 <- plot3 <- plot4 <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = .[,1], y = .[,2])) + 
  geom_text_repel(label = rownames(data)) + 
  geom_point(color = "blue") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  ggtitle("data title") + 
  labs(x = "xlabel", y = "ylabel") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+ 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, ncol = 2)
a<- menu(c("yes","no"), title="Make a choice")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to add a `pause(0.1)` between `grid.arrange` and `menu`